# Create new file with the contents of a string array taken from another file using methods (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, input

I am writing some code that takes each line of a txt file and stores it into a string. Afterward, the program will make a new file and store write the array into it.

This is the contents of the file:

```
04/26/16    Sega 3D Classics Collection
07/14/16    Batman: Arkham Underworld
06/24/16    Tokyo Mirage Sessions #FE
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't seem to store or make a new file once the method is running. The method to make the file into a string array works but it doesn't seem to take that array and write it on a brand new file. What I have tried is to use the FileWriter function to make a new file on my computer and use the writer function to write the array onto the file. Whenever I run or debug the program there is no new file in my computer.

This is the code I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
  public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File file = new File("releasedates.txt");

    input(file);
    

  }

  public static String[]input (File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[]arr = new String[3];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      arr[i] = sc.nextLine();

    }

    return arr;
    
  }

  public static void output(String filename, String[] info) throws IOException{

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("fileName.txt");
    writer.write(filename);
    writer.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping that running your `main()` method will read and write back out the contents of the file I'm seeing the following things that are preventing you from having the result you're looking for:

1. Your `main()` never calls the `output()` method that actually writes to the file.
2. Your `output()` method will write the value of `fileName` to the file, not the value of the `info` array that you pass in. You may have to call `Arrays.toString(info)` or iterate through its contents so the FileWriter can process it correctly.